# Search a pattern in the first 100 characters of a string

Tags: pcre

I want to display first 1000 characters of a string (literals are replaced by special symbol). I am using pcre library to replace the literal. After replacing every literal I am checking for the length of the string and if it is > 1000 then stop matching and display the string.

My problem is, Suppose I am sending a string with length 1GB, and if there is no literal in that string, pcre will check for the entire string. I want to search the pattern in the first 1000 characters. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The matching function pcre_exec() takes the string as a pointer and a
length. Just set the length to 1000 if you want to search only the first 
1000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just cut a 1000-chars head of your string and use substitution for it, not for the whole text.

In case you get less than 1000 chars after substitution, just cut another 1000-chars head, use  substitution and concatenate two results. Do it in loop until you get 1000-chars string or reach the end of the whole text.